# Kindle repair code 2 but cannot connect to computer

Tags: kindle-paperwhite

I have a Kindle 5.8.1 with the dreaded repair code 2. This I can fix but when I connect the device to my computer it will not come up as the Kindle and the best I can get is "Do you want to format this drive". The device has been replaced but if I can get it going it would be handy. Is it possible to reformat the device and reinstall the Kindle software? Any other ideas?

Comment: It has been replaced and the replacement still has the same error?

Comment: It's out of warranty so Amazon just wants to sell me another one. It has been replaced though so it's either a DIY repair or the recycling bin.